# Who are the captains for Madden 13 Ultimate Team?

Tags: madden-13

All the literature states that when you start an Ultimate Team in Madden 13, you'll choose a starting captain that will determine things like your stadium and jerseys. It also implies that there will be one starting captain for each team. Who are all of the starting captains for Madden 13 Ultimate Team?

Comment: Aaron Rodgers is my captain. There are also a lot of different quarterbacks, running backs, and some wide receivers. Remember that once you choose you can't ever change, so choose wisely.

Comment: also where is a lot changes to the ultimate team so excited got game yesturday

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you first start out in Madden Ultimate Team you have a choice from 32 captains:

- Brian Urlacher
- AJ Green
- Stevie Johnston
- Peyton Manning
- Joe Thomas
- Ronde Barber
- Larry Fitgerald
- Antonie Gate
- Dwayen Bowe
- Dwight Freeney
- Tony Romo
- Jake Long
- Lesean Mccoy
- Matt Ryan
- Patrick Willis
- Eli Manning
- M. Jones-Drew
- Darrelle Revis
- Ndamukong Suh
- Aaron Rodgers
- Cam Newton
- Tom Brady
- Darren Mcfadden
- Steven Jackson
- Ed Reed
- Brian Orakpo
- Drew Brees
- Marshawn Lynch
- Troy Polamalu
- Chris Johnson
- Adrian Peterson
- Andre Johnson

Do not be fooled by their initial rating shown, the players they show are the gold version you pull out of packs.

Good Luck!

Comment: I may give this an edit and make it a list so it's more readable, but thank you for the answer.